# What does @classmethod decorator in Python do internally?

Tags: python, python-decorators, class-method

I know how to use @classmethod decorator, but I wonder what does it do internally to the function, which it decorates? How does it take the class/object, on which it is called to pass it as first parameter of the decorated function?

Thanks

Comment: To know what it does *internally*, you'd need to deep-dive into some C: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Objects/funcobject.c#L782 Is that really what you want to know?

Comment: Here you can see a Python implementation: https://gist.github.com/carljm/3004616

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@classmethod is a Python descriptor - [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods), [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods)

You can call decorated method from an object or class.

```
class Clazz:

    @classmethod
    def f(arg1):
        pass

o = Clazz()
```

If you call:

```
o.f(1)
```

It will be acctually `f(type(o), *args)` called.

If you call:

```
Clazz.f(1)
```

It will be acctually `f(Clazz, *args)` called.

As in doc, pure-python classmethod would look like:

```
class ClassMethod(object):
"Emulate PyClassMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"

def __init__(self, f):
    self.f = f

def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
    if klass is None:
        klass = type(obj)
    def newfunc(*args):
        return self.f(klass, *args)
    return newfunc
```

Comment: Since Python 2 is now EOL, it would be better to link to Python 3 docs instead: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods

Comment: "@classmethod is a Python descriptor" is not correct, actually @classmethod is a Python decorator, see the documentation reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod